# Why do the determinants of the types $\det|f(i)+g(j)|$ and $\det|f(i)g(j)|$ vanish?

Tags: matrices, determinant

I find it very amusing that $$\det|f(i)+g(j)|_{n\times n}=0, n \ne 2~~~~~~(1)$$ and
$$\det|f(i)g(j)|_{n\times n}=0,n \ne 2.~~~~~(2)$$ Here, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$
are arbitrary functions and $i,j\in [1,n].$

This appears to be the characteristics of determinants. Have you experienced this? is it something trivial and warranted?!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what kind of "arbitrary functions" $f$ and $g$ are. Because adding, multiplying and taking determinants like that are not defined for arbitrary functions. Are they functions that take natural numbers from $1$ to $n$ as input and give real numbers as output?

Comment: @Arthur $det|i+j|, \det|i-j|, \det |i^2+j^2|, \det{\sini+\cosj$so on and so forth

Comment: I could guess that that's what you meant. However, the question as it is currently written doesn't make sense because of the ridiculously broad term "arbitrary functions". I am trying to get you to write the question so that it makes sense. That's important for readers of your question, but also a very good habit to get into for your own sake. Also in the name of clarity, for the first case you want $n>2$, and for the second case you want $n>1$ (remember that $1\times 1$ matrices are a thing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $a = (f(1), \ldots , f(n))^T$  and $b = (g(1), \ldots, g(n))^T$ the matrix
$$
 M_1 = (a_i b_j) = a b^T
$$
has zero as an eigenvalue if $n \ge 2$: $M_1 c = 0$ for every vector $c$ orthogonal to $b$. Therefore the determinant $(2)$ is zero.

Similarly, $(1)$ is the determinant of the matrix
$$
M_2 = a e^T + e b^T
$$
with $e = (1\ldots, 1)^T$. If $n\ge 3$ then there exists a vector $c$ orthogonal to both $e$ and $b$, so that $M_2 c = 0$.

Generally, a square matrix of the form $uv^T$ has the rank (at most) one, the sum of $k$ rank-one matrices has rank at most $k$, and $\det M = 0$ if the rank of $M$ is less than its dimension.

Answer (score 2):

A solution which uses only the elementary properties of determinants:

We have
$$\begin{vmatrix}
f(1)+g(1) & f(1)+g(2)& \cdots & f(1)+g(n)\\
f(2)+g(1) & f(2)+g(2) & \cdots & f(2)+g(n)\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(n)+g(1) & f(n)+g(2)  & \cdots & f(n)+g(n)\\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} f + g(1)e & f + g(2)e & \cdots & f+g(n)e\end{vmatrix}$$
where $f = \begin{bmatrix} f(1) \\ f(2) \\ \vdots \\ f(n)\end{bmatrix}$ and $e = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Subtract the first column from the rest to obtain

$$\begin{vmatrix} f + g(1)e & (g(2)-g(1))e & \cdots & (g(n)-g(1))e\end{vmatrix} = 0$$
since the columns are linearly dependent for $n \ge 3$.

For the second one we have

$$\begin{vmatrix}
f(1)g(1) & f(1)g(2)& \cdots & f(1)g(n)\\
f(2)g(1) & f(2)g(2) & \cdots & f(2)g(n)\\
\vdots & \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
f(n)g(1) & f(n)g(2)  & \cdots & f(n)g(n)\\
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} g(1)f & g(2)f & \cdots & g(n)f\end{vmatrix} = 0$$
since the columns are linearly dependent for $n \ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are true, but it is equation $(1)$ that only works for $n\gt2$ rather than equation $(2)$.
There is something called rank, and other things called eigenvalues, that you can look up, but you don't get taught until university.