# If $A=[ij(i+j)]_{n \times n}$, why $\det(A)=0$, when $n>2$

Tags: matrices, determinant

My numerical experiments suggest that if $A=[ij(i+j)]_{n \times n}$, then $\det(A)=0$, $i,j \in[1,n] $ and  $n>2.$
What could be an analytic proof for this observation? Can there be a general result?

**EDIT:**

Further, if $A=[(i+j)^k]_{n\times n}$, then $\det(A)=0$ for $n\ge 2+k$. The idea of degree of polynomial $k$  seems to work here according to the rank connection: $ rank(A+B+C+...) \le[ rank(A)+ rank(B)+rank(C)+...]$ or the matrices as pointed out by @orangeskid in his answer below.

This is why for $A=[i^k+j^k]_{n\times n}, k=1,2,3,4,5,...$ we have $\det(A)=0$ for $n\ge 3$ (independent of $k$).

Comment: Hint: It's $n$ rows of values of quadratic functions.

Comment: Even for $A=[i^3+j^3]_{n \times n}$ we get the same result.

Comment: Do you remember about the sum of rank one matrices? You were given the general result in the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3282904/42969

Comment: More generally: if $a(i,j), i, i, = 1..n$ are polynomials in $i$ and $j$ of degree $d$ then $det(A)=0$ for $n\ge d+2$.

Comment: It does not depend upon the degree of polynomial of $i,j$. For example for $A_{ij}=i^k+j^k (k=1,2,3,4,......), \det(A_{n\times n})=0, n\ge 3$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

It's a sum of two matrices of rank $1$, so at rank at most $2$.

Answer (score 3):

A general observation is that for real numbers $x_j$ and polynomials $q_1, \dots, q_n$ of degree $k<n-1$, the determinant with entries $q_i(x_j)$ has value zero.

Comment: It does not depend upon the degree of polynomial of $i,j$. For example for $A_{ij}=i^k+j^k(k=1,2,3,4,......), \det(A_{n×n})=0$ for $n≥3.$

Comment: @ZAhmed No, I stated the general case. Your special case doesn't invalidate my statement.

Comment: True, but $n > k+1$ understates the situation than the tight result  $k\ge 3$, in this case.

Comment: @ZAhmed Are you suggesting that I remove the restriction? That results in a false statement.

Comment: For $A=[i^5+j^5]$ as per your claim $\det(A)$ will nanish for $ n=7,8,9,....$ But the fact is that it vanishes even before for $n=3,4,5,6$; additionally. Your result is correct for $ (n>6)$ but it is silent about $ 3 \le n \le 6$.

Comment: @ZAhmed Ask a separate question. I will tell you why this has to be the case.

Comment: In order to answer my particular question you answered it with a generalization. You may see my edit where I have emphasized on the rank connection as hinted by @orangeskid which explains. If there is an exception to this I will get back to MSE again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's easily seen that $A$ is the sum of two rank-$1$ matrices. Let's try other ways.

One approach: compute the explicit rank factorization of $A$

Let $n\ge2$, and let $P$ the matrix formed by the first two columns of $A$ and $Q$ the $2\times n$ matrix such that:

$$Q_{1,j}=j(2-j)$$
$$Q_{2,j}=j(j-1)/2$$

If $M=PQ$, then

$$M_{i,j}=i(i+1)\times j(2-j)+2i(i+2)\times j(j-1)/2\\=ij(2i+2-ij-j+ij-i+2j-2)=ij(i+j)$$

That is, $M=A$ and $A=PQ$ is the [rank factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_factorization) of $A$.

Hence $A$ has rank $2$.

---

Another way:

Let $B$ the $n\times n$ matrix such that:

$$B_{i,j}=(-1)^{i+j}\binom{j-1}{i-1}$$

And $\det B=1$, since $B$ is an upper-triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal.

Let $C=AB$.

Then up to sign, the $i$-th row of $C$ is the [binomial transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_transform) of the $i$-th row of $A$:

$$C_{i,j}=\sum_{k=1}^j (-1)^{j+k}\binom{j-1}{k-1}A_{i,k}$$

Now an interesting property of the binomial transform is that the transform of a sequence that is a polynomial of degree $p$ is zero after the first $p+1$ terms.

This is due to the fact that the $j$-th term is the $j$-th [discrete difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Higher-order_differences) of the transformed sequence. Taking the index shift into account:

$$|C_{i,j}|=|\Delta^{j-1}A_{i,1}|,$$

where the difference is computed on the column index.

And the $j$-th difference of a polynomial of degree $k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-j$ if $j\le k$, and zero otherwise. It's easy to prove for monomials by induction on $j$, then by linearity it's proved for all polynomials.

That is, if the rows of $A$ are polynomials in $j$ of degree $k$, then $C$ has at most $k+1$ nonzero columns.

And since $\det A=\det C$, if $A$ has dimension greater than $k+1$, then $\det A=0$.

In your case, the rows of $A$ are polynomials of degree $2$ in $j$, so $\det A=0$ for $n>3$. This leaves the case $n=3$ as open, but it's easy to check that the determinant is zero too.

---

The previous argument is just another way to write that, for any matrix $A$, $\det A=\det C$ with $C_{i,j}=\Delta^{j-1}A_{i,1}$, where the forward difference is computed on the column index. This is due to the linearity of the determinant.